# xamarin form how to binding the child of a control

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

what's up?
I want to make a custom control that is ContentView, which has as children an entry and label I want to link (bind) the text field of the entry from the view, and tried different ways but it does not work
Any solution ?
Thank you

[imagen1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3nRO.png)

[imagen2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Nly0.png)

[imagen2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrN2p.png)

Comment: Please add your code here instead of attach images. Thanks!

Comment: As @NhanPhan says, put code in your question, no pictures. Also, what "different ways" have you tried? Put this information in your question, as it will help others answering your question.